# How do I type an object's key in an array in a type script?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, typescript2.0

I want to type the key values of the objects inside the already declared array.

```
const temp = [
  { key: "name", value: "mike" },
  { key: "gender", value: "male" },
];
```

I would like to extract the key values of the objects in the above temp array, name, gender, as a union type.

Comment: Can you update the question to include the desired output? See [ask].

Comment: I want to extract the key value used in the temp using the temp array as a union type.

I want to type => type Temp = "name" | "gender";

I want to extract the type by arrangement without writing the type myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add the `as const` annotation to your array declaration, then you can easily extract the type of the keys:

```
const temp = [
  { key: "name", value: "mike" },
  { key: "gender", value: "male" },
] as const;

type TempKey = (typeof temp)[number]["key"];
```